# Add filter to File Picker in android

Tags: android

Im selecting a file from file manager, now I want only (.rar, .zip, .apk) to be selectable, the rest are disabled. here's my code:

```
private void showFileChooser() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.setType("*/*");
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);

    try {
        startActivityForResult(
                Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select a File to Upload"),
                FILE_SELECT_CODE);
    } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
        // Potentially direct the user to the Market with a Dialog
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Please install a File Manager.",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case FILE_SELECT_CODE:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {



                Uri selectedFileUri = data.getData();
                selectedFilePath = FilePath.getPath(getActivity(),selectedFileUri);
                Log.i(TAG,"Selected File Path:" + selectedFilePath);


                bundleData.putString("appFile", selectedFilePath);
                btnAppFile.setText(getFileName(selectedFileUri));
            }
            break;
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

How to add type filter in this code?

Comment: It seems impossible for you to add a filter to system file chosser.What you can do is add a filter in`onActivityResult` to see whether the result is what you want.For example `uri.getPath().endWith(".apk")`.

Comment: can I just just use if statement to check if it passed the extension requirement? if yes, how can i get the file extension?

Comment: `uri.getPath().subString(uri.getPath().lastIndexOf("."))`  If the file has extension like `app.apk`,it returns `.apk`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this one?

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.setType("application/zip|application/x-rar-compressed");
startActivityForResult(intent, YOUR_REQUEST_CODE);
```

Comment: i will try this, how about .apk and .jar?

Comment: for APK: application/vnd.android.package-archive
for JAR: application/java-archive